# How do i disable SSL V3/TLS 1.0 for OpenLDAP or how do i disable TLS 1.0 support on ldap port 636?

Tags: ssl, openldap, tls1.2

Tried the following as per this article, https://access.redhat.com/articles/1474813

Place tls.ldif config file with below config instructions in it:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSProtocolMin
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.2
```

TLS 1.0 is still showing up as enabled for port 636. I need to enable support for tls 1.1 and higher. The above url provides solution for RHEL 7 but i am using RHEL 6, maybe that's a reason why this solution is not working for me.

Comment: There's more to it than just 'placing' a file. You have to feed it to `ldapmodify`,

Comment: Yes, did the following: ldapmodify -h host -D **cn=admin,cn=config -W -f ./tls.ldif** followed by **restarting of slapd service**. Still can see TLS 1.0 as enabled for port 636.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to Red Hat Identity Manager (and possibly also FreeIPA).

To set a minimum version of TLS for the Directory Server component, do the follwing:

1. Stop the dirsrv service: `systemctl stop dirsrv@YOUR-DOMAIN.service`
2. ensure that:`sslVersionMin: TLS1.2` 
   is set in the file `/etc/dirsrv/slapd-YOURDOMAIN-COM/dse.ldif`
3. Start the dirsrv service again: `systemctl start dirsrv@YOURDOMAIN-COM.service`

To check the offered TLS versions you can use the ssl-enum-ciphers script for nmap like so:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p636 localhost
```

The output should only show TLS versions higher than what you specified in the dse.ldif file:

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p636 localhost
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-13 12:03 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000070s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT    STATE SERVICE
636/tcp open  ldapssl
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

Keep in mind that this change needs to be done on all servers where the dirsrv service is running.